# How to resolve SerializationException saying XElement is not serializable

Tags: vb.net, serialization

How do I resolve this error in VB,net

> system.runtime.serialization.serializationexception: Type
>   'system.xml.linq.xelement' in Assembly 'system.xml.linq,
>   version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickey=b77a5c561934e089' is not
>   marked as serializable

I create a Grid that inherits from DataGridView. Oone of the Grid's properties is:

```
Public Property RowsXMLRegister As List(Of XElement) 
    Get 
        Return m_AllRowsXMLRegister 
    End Get 
    Set(value As List(Of XElement)) 
        m_AllRowsXMLRegister = value 
    End Set End 
Property
```

When I try placing the Grid on the form the error comes up.

Comment: What did you try to do that threw that exception?

Comment: Sounds like XElement might be being used as the type of a property on a Serializable class. Can you give some of the code that causes this, including the class definition of whatever it you want to serialize.

Comment: I create a Grid that inherits from DataGridView one of the Grid's property is:Public Property RowsXMLRegister As List(Of XElement)
        Get
            Return m_AllRowsXMLRegister
        End Get

        Set(value As List(Of XElement))
            m_AllRowsXMLRegister = value
        End Set
    End Property when I try placing the Grid on the form the error comes up

Comment: Yes Jon you are right the is the property definition>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Public Property RowsXMLRegister As List(Of XElement)
        Get
            Return m_AllRowsXMLRegister
        End Get

        Set(value As List(Of XElement))
            m_AllRowsXMLRegister = value
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: What is the Grid to do with that property?

Comment: Each row's info is stored in m_AllRowsXMLRegister in XML format. The property is used to access this info externally as expected